# Привязка скрипта python к определенному окну виндовс ( игре wow)

Tags: python, pillow

Есть скрипт Python , который следит за экраном игры wow, если появляется каптча, скрипт делая скриншоты экрана , видит что появилась каптча и делает действия по её решению.

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт или скриншоты делались именно в определенном окне. Как привязать к приложению скрипт или именно функцию скриншотов.

Сейчас мне нужно чтобы у меня на экране была игра, чтоб он работал. А я хочу, чтобы я мог делать свои дела и скриншоты делались именно игры, а не рабочего стола, это возможно?

```
import time
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
from PIL import ImageGrab
import math
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
import imagehash


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
average = [0, ]



def reshenie():
    pyautogui.moveTo(140, 270, 0.3)
    pyautogui.click()

    base_screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(814, 145, 1108, 170))
    base_screen.save('/Users/9/Documents/bot/base_screen.png')


    template = cv2.imread('base_screen.png', 0)
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]

     
    img_rgb = cv2.imread('base_screen.png')
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    scale_percent = 400
    width = int(img_gray.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(img_gray.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img_gray, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized_img, (3, 3), 0)
    blur_img = cv2.medianBlur(blur_img, 3)

    thresh, new_img = cv2.threshold(blur_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU |cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789-+?='
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(new_img, config=config))
    l = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_img, config=config)
    l = l.replace('?', '')
    l = l.replace('=', '')
    l = l.strip()


    a = ''
    b = ''

    for i in range(3):
        a = l[:l.index('+'):1]
        i += 1

    for i in range(3):
        b = l[l.index('+')+1::1]
        i += 1


     

    pyautogui.moveTo(874, 176, 0.3)
    pyautogui.click()

    print(int(a)+int(b))
    b = int(a)+int(b)
    b = str(b)
    pyautogui.write(b)

    pyautogui.moveTo(874, 222, 0.3)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(2)

while True:
    try:
        base_screen1 = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(21, 135, 317, 319))
        base_screen1.save('/Users/9/Documents/bot/base_screen1.png')

        img_1 = Image.open(r'base_screen1.png')
        img_2 = Image.open(r'captcha.png')
        hash = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('captcha.png'))
        hash2 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('base_screen1.png'))
        if hash == hash2:
            reshenie()
        else:
            continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
    except PermissionError:
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
    except ValueError:
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
    except OSError:
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что за скрипт, какую библиотеку он для скриншотов использует? И я вообще не уверен, что если окно с игрой будет в фоне, то там что-то будет отрисовываться. Игра тоже может следить в фоне она или в фокусе и менять от этого своё поведение.

Comment: Использует pillow imagegrab. Ну мне кажется невозможным, что в век нейросетей никто ни пользовался подобным. Игра отрисовывается в фоне, пусть меньше фпс, но отрисовывается. В любом случае, чем можно сделать так чтобы скриншоты делались с определенного окна, а не с рабочего стола. Или как по другому можно переписать скрипт.      Находил информацию по find window от win32gui но я не могу установить эту библиотеку и информации по ней мало. Должно же быт какое то решение для работы с окнами приложений. Для сетей есть Requests

Comment: Вам тут получается надо для двух библиотек этот вопрос решить - для `pyautogui` и для `PIL`. Первая двигает мышь и кликает, вторая грабит экран. Надо погуглить...

Comment: Гуглил пол дня, единственное что нашел это win32gui win32api но не смогу пока корректно поставить, думал может это старые библиотеки и есть новые решения, но вот пока не нашел